# How to traverse through all subdocuments in a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I want to traverse through all the subdocuments in a javascript object which might have multiple children inside array child, but it breaks down when I do it recursively.

It only happens when I exit 2 or more recursions, it exits the whole operation all together. It works perfectly fine if the objects have just one child uniformly. An object can have multiple children. Any irregular pattern in the number of children breaks the recursion.
I tried this in node and firefox but same results.

```
foo={name:"a",child:[
  {name:"b",child:[
    {name:"c",child:[
      {name:"d",child:[
        {name:"e",child:[]},
        {name:"f",child:[
          {name:"g",child:[
            {name:"h",child:[]}
          ]}
        ]}/*recursion crashes here*/,
        {name:"i",child:[]}
      ]},
      {name:"j",child:[
        {name:"k",child:[null]}
      ]}
    ]}
  ]}
]};

function recursiveDisplay(doc){
    process.stdout.write(doc.name+" ");
        for(i=0;i<doc.child.length;i++){
                recursiveDisplay(doc.child[i]);
    }
}

recursiveDisplay(foo);
```

Expected result: a b c d e f g h i j k ,
Actual result: a b c d e f g h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with the recursive function: the iterator `i` is a global variable, so recursive invocations will overwrite the value, causing the early exit you are seeing. This can be fixed by using a local iterator with `let i=0`.

Secondly, there is no check for `null` which is going to cause issues when you reach `"k"`. The following should solve both:

```
function recursiveDisplay(doc){
    process.stdout.write(doc.name+" ");
    for(let i=0;i<doc.child.length;i++){
        if (doc.child[i]){
            recursiveDisplay(doc.child[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
function recursiveDisplay(doc) {
  console.log(doc.name + " ")
  doc.child.filter(Boolean).forEach(rec)
}
```

In order to get rid of the `null` and `undefined` values, I take the `child` array, filter out the `falsy` values (so any `false`, `undefined`, `null` etc ...) then call `recursiveDisplay` on each of them.